# ZipArchive created with C# does not contain any entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to create a zipfile in ASP.NET MVC a single PDF file within it. However, using the code below, an empty zipfile is created. Can someone please advise what I am doing incorrectly?

```
public FileResult DownloadZipfile(string html)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

    byte[] rawDownload = PDFConverterUtils.PdfSharpConvert(html);

    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry("MyPDF.pdf");

    using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
    {
        streamWriter.BaseStream.Write(rawDownload, 0, rawDownload.Length);
    }

    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip) { FileDownloadName = "test.zip" };

}
```

Comment: Why do you have an async method with no awaits?

Comment: Sorry and thank you. That is because I removed the portion of the method that refines `html` for brevity. I'll edit the method.

Comment: Have your verified the pdf data if you just write the `rawDownload` bytes to disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using a `ZipArchive` with a `MemoryStream`, I would suggest resetting the position of the stream after writing to it so that the content of the stream can be read by the response.

```
public FileResult DownloadZipfile(string html) {
    
    byte[] rawDownload = PDFConverterUtils.PdfSharpConvert(html);
    
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using(ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(
        stream: memoryStream, 
        mode: ZipArchiveMode.Create, 
        leaveOpen: true //To leave the memory stream open after disposal
    )){
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry("MyPDF.pdf");
        using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open()) {
            entryStream.Write(rawDownload, 0, rawDownload.Length);
        }
    }
    memoryStream.Position = 0;//reset memory stream position for read
    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip) {
        FileDownloadName = "test.zip" 
    };
}
```

As suggested in another answer you should dispose of the archive to force it to write its content to its underlying memory stream, but take note of the following

> #### [ZipArchive.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158289(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)
>
> Unless you construct the object by using the [`ZipArchive(Stream, ZipArchiveMode, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137431(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor overload and set its `leaveOpen` parameter to `true`, all underlying streams are closed and no longer available for subsequent write operations.
>
> When you are finished using this instance of `ZipArchive`, call `Dispose()` to release all resources used by this instance. You should eliminate further references to this `ZipArchive` instance so that the garbage collector can reclaim the memory of the instance instead of keeping it alive for finalization.

Because you want to make use of the memory stream after writing to it, you need to make sure that it remains open, and that the position of the stream is reset to the beginning so that the content of the stream can be read from the start.